# AWS Redshift Serverless Data Catalog Auto-mount not working properly

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-serverless

I am relatively new to Redshift Serverless. My goal is to perform ETL tasks on data currently stored in S3 and available in the Glue Data Catalog. I can see the 'awsdatacatalog' schema in query editor v2 under my workgroup and I was able to
`<GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE awsdatacatalog to "IAMR:MyRole">`
I can perform SELECTs on the data but I am unable to run INSERTs.

`GRANT INSERT ON TABLE awsdatacatalog.my_db.my_table to "IAMR:MyRole"`
This fails with the following error message:

> ERROR: Auto-mounting of AWS Glue Catalog is not enabled on this cluster / namespace.

My user is listed as superuser ("usesuper":"true") under pg_user yet I am unable to run:
`SHOW data_catalog_auto_mount;` --> returning:

> ERROR: must be superuser to examine "data_catalog_auto_mount"

HOWEVER!
I was able to run:
`ALTER SYSTEM SET data_catalog_auto_mount = on;` --> returning:
`Info: Reboot to apply configuration change.`

But the setting never changed (I don't think) and the official guide states that the reboot happens when there are no tasks being performed on the workgroup. I'v deleted the connection to the workgroup for a night and nothing happened.

Comment: I can confirm that the message "ERROR: must be superuser to examine "data_catalog_auto_mount"" is returned even if you are connected as the admin user. My suspicion is that this feature and its documentation were developed for Redshift Serverless, and is only marginally supported on the Redshift cluster.